# postgres doesn't drop not null

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I drop `not null` on primary key column, and it executes, after I check schema of table and there is `not null`

table:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table warehouses
(
    id_warehouse       serial      not null
        constraint warehouse_pkey
            primary key,
    responsible_person varchar(30) not null
);
```

script to drop not null:

```
alter table warehouses
    drop constraint warehouse_pkey;

alter table warehouses
    alter id_warehouse drop not null;

alter table warehouses
    add constraint warehouse_pkey
        primary key (id_warehouse);
```

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` has to be `NOT NULL` so when you did `primary key (id_warehouse)` you implicitly added a `NOT NULL`. If you don't want that then make the constraint be `UNIQUE` instead of `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: [demo - metadata](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9b0f31e07dff141f04683ce5c649fc44)

Comment: You want to have as many `NOT NULL` columns as possible, so that your data have good quality and your SQL statements become simple and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per information here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

> PRIMARY KEY (column constraint)

> The PRIMARY KEY constraint specifies that a column or columns of a table can contain only unique (non-duplicate), nonnull values. Only one primary key can be specified for a table, whether as a column constraint or a table constraint.

A column defined as `PRIMARY KEY` will also have the `NOT NULL` constraint set.